# SQL Server 2000, ADO 2.8, VB6

Tags: sql-server, vb6, ado

How to determine if a Transaction is active i.e. before issuing Begin Transaction I want to ensure that no previous transaction are open.. the platform is VB6, MS-SQL Server 2000 and ADO 2.8

Answer (score 6):

You can check the @@TRANCOUNT variable, for the current connection to the database. It gets incremented by 1 every time a transaction is opened.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933178(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: +1 For Khalid, you can retrieve this with a SELECT @@TRANCOUNT